# Tensorflow 2: Customized Loss Function works differently from the original Keras SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss

I just started to work with tensorflow 2.0 and followed the simple example from its official website.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(t_x, t_y), (v_x, v_y) = mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

lossFunc = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=lossFunc,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(t_x, t_y, epochs=5)
```

The output for the above code is:

```
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 60us/sample - loss: 2.5368 - accuracy: 0.7455
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.5846 - accuracy: 0.8446
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.4751 - accuracy: 0.8757
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.4112 - accuracy: 0.8915
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.3732 - accuracy: 0.9018
```

However, if I change the lossFunc to the following:

```
def myfunc(y_true, y_pred):
    return lossFunc(y_true, y_pred)
```

which just simply wrap the previous function, it performs totally differently. The output is:

```
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 60us/sample - loss: 2.4444 - accuracy: 0.0889
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.5696 - accuracy: 0.0933
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.4493 - accuracy: 0.0947
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.4046 - accuracy: 0.0947
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.3805 - accuracy: 0.0943
```

The loss values are very similar but the accuracy values are totally different. Anyone knows what is the magic in it, and what is the correct way to write your own loss function?

Comment: The loss does not seem to have changed too much. it might be something with how you apply your metric.  Can you share the part of the code when you apply your custom loss as well?

Comment: It is very simple. Just replace the loss function with the new one.
```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=myfunc,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The rest of the code is totally same. The above code is easy to run once you have installed tensorflow 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use built-in loss function, you can use 'accuracy' as metric . Under the hood, tensorflow will select appropriate accuracy function (in your case it is `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()`).

When you define custom_loss function, then tensorflow doesn't know which accuracy function to use. In this case, you need to explicitly specify that it is `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()`. Please check the [gist hub gist here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Advanced-Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/custom_loss_keras.ipynb).

#### The code modification and the output is as follows

```
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model2.add(layers.Flatten())
model2.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model2.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model2.add(layers.Dense(10))

lossFunc = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=myfunc,
              metrics=['accuracy',tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
model2.fit(t_x, t_y, epochs=5)
```

#### output

```
Train on 60000 samples
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 81us/sample - loss: 2.2295 - accuracy: 0.0917 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.7483
Epoch 2/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 76us/sample - loss: 0.5827 - accuracy: 0.0922 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8450
Epoch 3/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 76us/sample - loss: 0.4602 - accuracy: 0.0933 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8760
Epoch 4/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 76us/sample - loss: 0.4197 - accuracy: 0.0946 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8910
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 76us/sample - loss: 0.3965 - accuracy: 0.0937 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8979
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5095286780>
```

Hope this helps